# Convert Hex to Hex with base 2 python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How i convert number HEX with base 1 (0x1) to base 2 (0x01).

Hex_B1 = 0x1
Hex_B2 = 0x01

hex(int('110', 2)) = 0x06

Comment: I think you mean you want leading zeros?

Comment: If you Google the phrase "Python convert hex to binary", you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Comment: You are using the wrong terminology here. Hex is a base 16 numerical notation, *base 2* is binary. You are instead trying to format hexadecimal to using 2 *digits*, padding with zero as needed.

Comment: @GuiLuiz  You mean converting _binary_ (base 2) to hex (base 16) ?

Answer (score 0):

Because `hex` produces a string, you can just parse the string after conversion to hex.

```
leading_zeros = 2

str_hex = hex(int('110', 2))
final_hex = '0x'+str_hex[2:].zfill(leading_zeros)
```

---

As pointed out by Martijn Pieters in the comments, the much better solution is to use Pythons built in `format` function.

```
format(5, '#04x')
```

Comment: The correct solution is to not use the `hex()` function to begin with. `format(value, '#04x')` would give you the correct format without string concatenation and `str.zfill()` calls.

Comment: @Martijn maybe with a `value & 0xFF` if needing to restrict - depends what the OP's really after though...

Comment: @MartijnPieters Much better solution (though you actually need `'#04x'). Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @Stephen: ah yes, I always forget to adjust the full width when adding `#`...